# How can I create a new instance of a class using "this" from within method?

Tags: typescript

I am looking for a way to call new `this` from within a class method.

```
class Example {
  fork() {
    return new this();
  }
}

const x = new Example().fork(); // instance of example

class Alpha extends Example {}

const x = new Alpha().fork(); // expected instance of Alpha but is example
```

Answer (score 5):

I assume you mean you want to call `new this.constructor()` (see [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor)) and not `new this()`, since it is vanishingly rare that the instance of a class will also be a class constructor.  At runtime this is all you need.

---

Unfortunately the typing for `constructor` in TypeScript is messy.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#3841](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841) for details, but the main issue is that since subclass constructors can require a different set of arguments from their superclass constructors, if `this.constructor` were strongly typed, then many `class` hierarchies would fail to form a valid subtype hierarchy and would therefore violate [substitutatibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

So in TypeScript, `constructor` is typed only as `Function`, and therefore `new this.constructor()` will yield an error:

```
return new this.constructor(); // error!
// This expression is not constructable.
```

In order to tell the compiler that `this.constructor` is a zero-arg constructor function, you'll have to either use a type assertion like this:

```
class Example {
  fork(): this {
    return new (this.constructor as new () => this)()
  }
}
```

or add a strongly-typed `constructor` property declaration to your class like this:

```
class Example2 {
  ['constructor']: new () => this
  fork(): this {
    return new this.constructor()
  }
}
```

Both solutions work for your presented example use case:

```
const x = new Example().fork(); // Example
class Alpha extends Example { }    
const y = new Alpha().fork(); // Alpha
```

But neither solution will prevent you from calling `fork()` on an instance of a subclass whose constructor requires a parameter

```
class Blop extends Alpha {
  constructor(x: string) {
    super();
    console.log(x.toUpperCase());
  }
}
const z = new Blop("oops").fork(); // error at runtime!!
```

Without a good solution to microsoft/TypeScript#3841, I think this might be the best you can get.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAWhBOB7AgvA5gYWI+AeAKgHxQC8UAdhAO5QAUAlKcfgNwBQbAxgDYCGAzvygBRAB68AtmG7QA3lDZQoAMxwBrBgC4owABYBLIbMVKo8CMACu8chWp09hgHSdE5fsHiXO2eFAF2NAxMOgb89AwmAL5sMWz65MAIyryc0GKS0hAATFDGSq7unt6+2pRBjCTEjvyxXHyCIuJSMrn5UADaAOSFHl4+OF0AumX2wVWhhiaq8Br02jV5JkrmVjaBk-wubn0lOJFKMXG9wFCipBsZLRAMTjNzLFAA9E9NmTIcPAJCyNxgurwoBBRElyAATIRXLJ5KDHHanEAXcpQX7-Xi3e4MR4vFF-AGfBpCABC3EQYCBIIg4J+eMB7RO-V8tFE2j6CTQjHaSn4lkg8CxyygvUQMicpLQzKc2AAqmA+RgBDd6PR2Ic6icoAAvJH2Elk2gAIkQZP4Bvod3UWOerwQSD8vFOXkS+gkEAAhG6gA)

Comment: Thank you for this extensive response, there's a lot of good learnings and tricks here, and I really appreciate you taking the time to put this answer together.